# Problems after broom update?

Tags: r, broom

I had this piece of code to run multiple linear models at once separated per levels of a factor. First, I subset the data with `filter` and `group_by` and then built the model with `do()` and exibit the output with `tidy()`

```
dados <- read.table("Rafael_bovo_dados2.txt", h=TRUE)
dim(dados)#dimensões da tabela
head(dados); str(dados)

df_lm <- dados %>%
       filter(Species == "Physalaemus_cuvieri") %>%
       group_by(Mountain_Range) %>%
       do(mod = lm(EWL_ug~as.factor(Altitude),data = .))

df_lm %>%
  tidy(mod)
```

This last line used to return a table with the summary statistics and other results of all those models, like the ones in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html). However, this now returns an error saying that tidy is deprecated.

```
Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Data frame tidiers are deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release of broom. 
2: `data_frame()` is deprecated as of tibble 1.1.0.
Please use `tibble()` instead.
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated. 
3: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

How can I change the code for it to return the whole table with statistics and P values?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I was able to adapt the code:

```
df_lm <- dados %>%
       filter(Species == "Physalaemus_cuvieri") %>%
       nest_by(Mountain_Range) %>%
      mutate(mod = list(lm(EWL_ug~as.factor(Altitude),data = data)))

df_lm %>%
  summarise(broom::tidy(mod))
```

now it returns what I expected:

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Mountain_Range' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   Mountain_Range [2]
  Mountain_Range   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>            <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Serra_da_Mantiq… (Intercept)   2.93       0.188    15.6   7.68e- 9
2 Serra_da_Mantiq… as.factor(…  -0.497      0.226    -2.19  5.07e- 2
3 Serra_do_Mar     (Intercept)   2.70       0.149    18.1   5.33e-13
4 Serra_do_Mar     as.factor(…  -0.0669     0.201    -0.333 7.43e- 1
```